# windows subsystem Linux cannot find files in the terminal

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using window 10 system.
I have assessed the home directory of the WSL and manually move a python file into the following address

C:\Users\assa8\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\lxr\demo

However, the python file did not show up when I use the 'ls'  command in the Linux terminal and I also could not run it using command lines. It appears the file did not exist when I tried to access it through the terminal.

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WSL1 then the recommendations are to not under any situations edit or modify any Linux files inside of your `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder using Windows apps or tools which includes moving files using file explorer. See this blog post from Microsoft https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

If you are Using WSL2 that is a slightly different issue of which i cant help you right now as i am still using WSL1

You should do your dev work in the `/mnt/c/` sub folders in WSL which will allow you to easily edit those same files on windows. Personally I work in a folder `c:\projects\` which is mapped to `/mnt/c/projects/` in WSL.

Comment: I am not sure what WSL i am using. I download the Ubuntu from Microsoft store. I installed WSL in the terminal just now and i checked the version which shows 0.2.1. Are you suggesting that if I am using WSL 1, I can manually move the files to C:\Users\assa8\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\mnt\c   
and proceed what I wanted to do?

Comment: Actually i can just assess the files in the following directory now. C:\Users\assa8\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\lxr\demo

I think the only change i made was running sudo apt install wsl

Comment: If you have Windows build 18917 or higher you will have WSL2, lower and it will be WSL1. if you have WSL1 i would highly recommend you read the article i linked to and do not edit files in that location you can corrupt the WSL filesystem and you will lose your work. Always work from the /mnt/c or similar.

Comment: Also `sudo apt install wsl` does not make any sense to me? you install wsl from within windows which does not have the concept of sudo.